# 502 error nothing is listening on port 8000 nginx

Tags: django, nginx, configuration, gunicorn, bad-gateway

I have ran into a problem when trying to deploy my web server, where I'm getting a 502 bad gateway error.

When looking in the nginx error logs, I get this:

```
failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "example.com"
```

I then ran `sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :8000` to see if anything is listening on port 8000, but got no output, meaning that indeed nothing is listening on port 8000.

Also, here are my nginx configurations in sites-enabled:

```
upstream app_server {
     server unix:/home/daniel/myproject/myproject.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 138.197.152.54;
    client_max_body_size 50M;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/daniel/myproject;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    # proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_connect_timeout 30;
    proxy_read_timeout 30;
}
```

I'm wondering if the port the server is listening on is false, since the proxy pass has 127.0.0.1:**8000**, and on top, the server is apparently listening on port **80**.

Is something wrong with my configurations? I'm quite new to working with nginx, gunicorn, and would very much appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Port 8000 is what `nginx` expects `gunicorn` to be listening on. You seem to be confusing Unix sockets with TCP/IP sockets. What does your `gunicorn` configuration look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I find out that indeed the problem was with my nginx configurations.
specifically, the solution was to change the setting for **proxy_pass**.

Instead of it being `proxy_pass     http://127.0.0.1:8000`, it should be:

`proxy_pass     http://unix:/home/daniel/myproject/myproject.sock;`

Of course, change **daniel**, **myproject** and **myproject.sock** with your actual files and directory names.

I got all this information from this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04